# How to apply rules to service account Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How can i put the Cloud-Firestore rules to apply to the service accounts? Like from the java admin API the only way to form connection to the database is to use the service account which bypasses all the rules. It doesnt make any sense what am i missing? Or is there some different way to form connection to the database without using the service account like this

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(ServiceAccount.json))
.setDatabaseUrl("DataBaseURL")
.build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

I want to like add this to a open source project so it would be not ideal that everyone has full access to the database. So i want the rules to apply but idk how? if you can only use the service accounts.

If its not possible to apply the rules to the service accounts then how do i form a connection without the service account? if thats impossible too then whats the point of the rules

Edit: Theres no way of applying the rules to the service account which is a shame also in the java-Admin SDK You cant form connection directly to the database without the service account so the only way of doing this would make some kind of Rest API where you send an request and it will execute it.

Comment: You will have to implement, in your server an authentication and an authorisation mechanism, and implement, in your Cloud Function, your own rules (through bespoke business logic), based on the authorisation level of each user type.

Answer (score 0):

Security rules are applied to any access to Firestore directly from client-side SDKs, such as the ones for Android, iOS, and client-side JavaScript.

There is no way to apply security rules to a client that accesses Firestore with a service account, like with the Admin SDKs for Java, Go and Node.js. Such clients run with administrative privileges in what is assumed to be a privileged environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. These connections by definition bypasses security rules, and there's no way to change this behavior.

Comment: So using the Java API theres no way of making any connection to the database where the security rules would apply?

Comment: Correct. Connections from the Admin SDK to Firestore by definition bypasses security rules, and there's no way to change this behavior.

Comment: Yeah. and there doesnt seem to be any other SDK than the Admin SDK for Java. Well damn

Comment: Mhm. Do you know why does it have the rules option in the first place tho? If the only way u can access the database is with the service account and that bypasses the rules

Comment: "why does it have the rules option" What is "it" in this case? Firebase has server-side security rules because it allows access to the database directly from client-side apps, where you can't trust the code to be correct. Code that uses the Admin SDKs is assumed to be trusted, and for that reason bypasses the security rules./